# How to make a flushometer toilet look nicer?

Tags: toilet, tankless

I'm the new owner of a 3 bed, 2 bath condo in Chicago, built in 1923. It's lovely and old. Both toilets are flushometer style, tankless. They look exactly like a toilet you'd see in a public school (which is to say, functional but not nice).

I'm wondering if there's a way to make these puppies look nicer (ie, covering up all the exposed metal stuff that's behind the bowl and comes out of the wall) without actually having to replace the toilets entirely? They work fine, they just look...not that nice. Also it's annoying to flush them when the toilet lid is up.

Thanks all!

They generally look like this, for reference: [image]

Comment: mounting the bowl square to the wall would help, but I'm guessing that's not your one,

Comment: There's plenty of potential there is you want to go steampunk!

Answer (score 1):

Clean and tidy is fine.

Many find the « classic » look engaging, whimsical, different so if they are working leave well alone.

Seriously though, if the toilet is dirty they will complain but I doubt they will complain « nice clean toilet, but I don’t like the flush mechanism »...

So, clean, tidy with good paper and see if you get comments down the line.

Comment: I'm not renting this place, I live here so I'm not worried about what others think about it :) I'm curious if I can make it look nicer for my own sake. But I agree, it's definitely...vintage! Not inherently a bad thing.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I had an idea it was a BnB... Looks like you will be coming up with a shelf of some sort. Have seen some similar fittings painted to look like people ie comedy faces etc but that is another taste...

Answer (score 1):

They look fine to me, but then I don't have to use them everyday. You could make a cover out of plywood and tile it or paint it. Turn it into a shelf.